# How do I link Qt 5.6 with MVS 2015?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015, qt5.6

I have downloaded Qt opensource library version 5.6 and been through the installation steps provided.

I have added the bin folder to my path environment as well as the include environment and the lib variables.

I also installed the Qt 5 package extension for visual studio 2015.

The first error I have when I attempt to create a Qt application project is:

"Cannot instantiate QTProjectEngine object!"

My second error:

When loading a template project and try to run the program in debug mode, I get the error:
"The following error occurred:
 There's no QT version assigned to this project for platform Win32. Please use the 'Change QT version' feature and choose a valid Qt version for this platform."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you may need to configure Qt versions first. Note: the VS extension and installed packages are not initially connected anyhow (though extension may attempt to search for one, not sure).

In VS 2013 and Qt 5.4 to configure Qt version:

1. From the main menu select *Qt/Qt options*
2. Click *Add* and enter correct values, example path: C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc_2013_64